# android out of memory for including some image buttons

Tags: android, image, button, out-of-memory

Actually I have for so long wish to know how to present graphics in a proper way.

In an activity, I have the following:

- a background (png, full screen, 768*1280, 1.36MB)
- 3 icons (each icon has pressed and not pressed: 2 states, using 1 png 400 * 400, 300KB each), i.e. 3 icon * 2 pic * 300KB = 1.8MB
- some more textviews

When the app starts off and directly goes to this activity, everything is ok, the activity can be presented properly.

Yet somehow when the app has run for some other activities, and then goes to this activity through a dialog box, then most of the time errors will occur, as follows:

```
Out of memory on a 15728656-byte allocation.
```

### Question:

I have researched for sometime and some say to bitmap.recycle(), yet how to implement? through the onCreate? or actually 400*400 is too big?

If I want to change the background of an activity upon users' choice, i.e. when he presses button A, the background changes to bgdA, presses button B will change background to bgdB... in that way how that can be achieved?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where your asset is stored is the amount of memory it might take, since scaling factor is calculated between the difference of densities, this is a little gray area because I haven't found any official android documentation that backs this info up, however I've seen that error so many times and this is the way I handle it.

1.- If you don't have the asset in the proper drawable-(density), this will cause problems because depending on the devices you are actually supporting, you should put the asset in drawable-xxhdpi or drawable-xhdpi, you will notice how the memory will decrease considerably

2.- If you don't want to mess with densities because it's a generic image which don't have much details(like a simple background), then add the asset in the drawable-nodpi folder, it will prevent android from trying to scale the asset it self..

3.- As good practice, try to create the asset with the proper size for the proper densities, 400 x 400 seems like too much for an icon, this will also prevent you from OOM, not only in this activity, but for other activities that might also need to load a good amount of assets, giving scalability to your app..

Always take on count that leaving the "resize" of an Image to the OS might cause huge amounts of memory allocated because the OS will try to resize it based on the formula width * height * 4bytes, the 4 byes are for ARGB of each pixel, 1 byte per color or alpha, so if your image is for example 1090 * 1920, it could easily become internally 8.3MBs even tho the actual image size is only a few KBs, and if it tries to scale it, it might double it's size too.

Hope this Helps

Regards!

Comment: thanks for your most detailed answer! I really do not know there are difference putting images to those different drawable folders. I have followed by shrinking the images to 100*100 (really can see it starts to be blur), putting the image to drawable-hdpi, and also to release the mediaplayer before getting to the activity, and now it works much faster and so far does not meet out-of-memory..thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a copy of your image for every drawable folder in you res, for example if you runnig your app on the S4 phone and you don't have all the images in the drawable-xxhdpi folder you will run out of memory even with reasonably small images.

Also if you need to change background at run time use setBackgroundResource.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is the common problem in android here is the proper solution 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
 In easy words you have to scale the image down according to your requirement

Comment: I would like to know how about the background of an activity? does it need to be performed by Loading a Scaled Down Version into Memory using BitmapFactory?

Comment: I didn't get your point, if you are trying to say that you are setting background of the activity then let me tell you in any case at any time images can cause problem due to the small amount of memory so its better to scale the image